# How to choose father node only (child node not)with Vuetify Treeview

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any way to make the node not selected when I check the father node in Vuetify Treeview with selectable on? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I am using the treeview now, and I set the selectable as true,but there is a problem that if I make the father node checked all the child node are checked,I want only the father node is checked. E.g, There is a father node named "father",it has three child nodes,"child1","child2","child3",I want to choose both the father node and child1,Is there any way?